Kustomize fails with Error: no matches for Id ScaledObject.v1alpha1.keda.sh
My base template is the following
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: azure-queue-auth
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: azure | azure-workload
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: jobservices-snowflakeuploader-deployment
  namespace: jobservices-snowflakeuploader
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1        
    kind: Deployment     
    name: jobservices-snowflakeuploader-deployment
  minReplicaCount:  1                   
  maxReplicaCount:  5
  triggers:
  - type: azure-queue
    metadata:
      queueName: sailpoint-arm-jobservices-snowflakeuploadmodel-request
      accountName: saarmdatarepodevf02
      queueLength: "2"
    authenticationRef:
        name: azure-queue-auth

My overlay is the following
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: jobservices-snowflakeuploader-deployment
  namespace: jobservices-snowflakeuploader
spec:
  triggers:
  - type: azure-queue
    metadata:
      accountName: saarmdatarepoqaf02


When I run kusotmize build, I am getting the following error
Error: no matches for Id ScaledObject.v1alpha1.keda.sh/jobservices-snowflakeuploader-deployment.jobservices-snowflakeuploader; failed to find unique target for patch ScaledObject.v1alpha1.keda.sh/jobservices-snowflakeuploader-deployment.jobservices-snowflakeuploader

My repo structure contains base/scaled-object.yaml and overlays/qa-eastus2-002/scaled-object-patch.yaml
My kustomize file contains
patchesStrategicMerge:
- scaled-object-patch.yaml

What am I missing?

My base directory kustomization.yaml file didn't contain
-scaled-object.yaml

